# PHP variable into form ($username)

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="POST">
  <h1>Enquiries</h1>
  <span><h2 class="required">*Required</h2></span>

  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="sr-only">Firstname</label>
    <input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="<?php print_r($username)?>" />
  </div>
  <label class="sr-only">Lastname</label>
  <input class="text" type="text" name="Lastname" placeholder="*" required>

  <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
  <input class="text" type="text" name="email" placeholder="">

  <label class="sr-only">Subject</label>
  <input type="text" name="password" class="text" placeholder="*">

  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Comment:</label>
  <textarea id="text" placeholder="Write something..." required> </textarea>

  <input type="submit" action="submit.php">
```

I need to input my `$username` into the `firstname` input field. How can I set the automatic value to be `$username` When a logged in user goes to send an enquiry.

Comment: Use `echo` instead of `print_r`?

Comment: Sorry yeah i tried that, was just trying to mess with it, still not working.

Comment: Please define an `automatic value`.

Comment: What output does it show? What's the type of `$username`?

Comment: Make sure that `$username` variable is set and have some value. Also this page extension need to be `.php` not `.html`

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 3):

```
<input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo isset($username) ? $username : '' ?>" />
```

Comment: I am logged into my site but its showing blank after i inputted your code.

Comment: @Lucasirusta  as i said Make sure that `$username` variable is set and have some value. Also this page extension need to be `.php` not `.html`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `echo` instead of `print_r`. Also check if the variable exists.

```
<input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo !empty($username) ? $username : ''; ?>" />
```

Comment: Still blank, not sure.

Comment: @Lucasirusta: it means `$username` is empty... basic PHP.

Comment: @chris85: you're absolutely right. Didn't know it... I thought print_r on string returns similar result as var_dump... Don't want to delete this answer, due to comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
<input class="text" type="text" name="name" value="<?= $username ?>" />
```

Will fix it if the variable username has been initialized prior

Comment: short tags aren't always enabled, it's not a good idea to recommend them.